# Error: jquery.min.js return 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I create a web application in asp.net MVC 4 with entity framework 6.0.
in which I create detail(list) of data. on the top of the list give one button to add some data. On click of the edit button, the form will open in a bootstrap modal popup. it is working fine. In detail page, every row has edited and delete button from that user can delete the record.
Now on click of an edit button popup will open with data..but now this does not work well.it gives me an error of **500 Internal server error in the jquery.min.js file.**
here I put some code snippet for better understanding.

This is my CurrencyDetail page

```html
@model IEnumerable<RedICMVC.Models.Currency>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CurrencyDetail";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">
        <div class="card-icon">
            <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
        </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">Currency Details</h4>
        <p style="float:right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEdit()">
                <i class="material-icons">add</i>Add Currency
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="material-datatables">
            <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive table-hover text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SR)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Currency1)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cur_Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MainCurrency)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CoinCurrency)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExRate)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("GetRecordFromId","Currency", new { id = item.SR })" class="commanId" Value="@item.SR">
                                    <i class="material-icons icon_size">edit</i>
                                </a>|
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.SR" data-target="#confirmDelete" data-title="Delete Currency" data-message="Are you sure you want to delete this currency ?">
                                    <i class="material-icons icon_size">delete</i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SR)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency1)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cur_Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MainCurrency)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoinCurrency)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExRate)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.Partial("DialogBox", "Home")
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="model1" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                @*<h4 class="modal-title">Add Unit</h4>*@
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modelBody">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        var AddEdit = function (SR) {
            var url = "/Currency/AddCurrency?id=" + SR;
            $("#modelBody").load(url, function () {
                $("#model1").modal("show");
            })
        }
        $('.commanId').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.get("/Currency/GetRecordFromId?id=" + id, function (data, status) {
                debugger;
                var url = "/Currency/GetRecordFromId?id=" + id;
                $("#modelBody").load(url, function () {
                    $("#model1").modal("show");
                })
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

This is my AddCurrency Page

```html
@model RedICMVC.Models.SpCurrency

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddCurrency";
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header card-header-rose card-header-icon">
        <div class="card-icon">
            <i class="material-icons">details</i>
        </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">Add Currency</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddCurrency", "Currency", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="form-group require">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Currency, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Currency" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Currency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cur_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Currency Name" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cur_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainCurrency, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Main Currency" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCurrency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CoinCurrency, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Coin Currency" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoinCurrency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Excext Rate" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExRate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd" name="Save" value="Save">
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd" name="reset" value="Reset">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here is My controller

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RedICMVC.Models;
using RedICMVC.Common.Toaster;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace RedICMVC.Controllers.Masters
{
    public class CurrencyController : Controller
    {
        protected RedICMVCDBEntities Db = new RedICMVCDBEntities();
        // GET: Currency
        public ActionResult CurrencyDetail()
        {
            var sprecult = Db.Currencies.ToList();
            return View(sprecult);
        }
        public ActionResult AddCurrency()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCurrency(SpCurrency cr)
        {
            if (cr.SR == 0)
            {
                var spresult = Db.Sp_Currency_Insert(cr.Currency, cr.Cur_Name, cr.MainCurrency, cr.CoinCurrency, cr.ExRate);
                if (spresult == 1 || spresult == -1)
                {
                    this.AddToastMessage("Success!!", "Currency Added Succesfully!!", ToastType.Success);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.AddToastMessage("Error!!", "Something Went To Wrong.!! Please try again.", ToastType.Error);
                }
                ModelState.Clear();
                return RedirectToAction("CurrencyDetail");
            }
            else
            {
                var spresult = Db.Sp_Currency_Update(cr.SR, cr.Currency, cr.Cur_Name, cr.MainCurrency, cr.CoinCurrency, cr.Symbol, cr.ExRate);
                if(spresult==1||spresult==-1)
                {
                    this.AddToastMessage("Success!!", "Currency Updated Succesfully!!", ToastType.Success);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.AddToastMessage("Error!!", "Something Went To Wrong.!! Please try again.", ToastType.Error);
                }
                ModelState.Clear();
                return RedirectToAction("CurrencyDetail");
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetRecordFromId(int id)
        {
            var idParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "SR",
                Value = id
            };
            var courseList = Db.Database.SqlQuery<SpCurrency>("exec sp_Currency_Get @SR", idParam).FirstOrDefault<SpCurrency>();
            return View("AddCurrency", courseList);
        }

        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var spresult = Db.sp_Currency_Delete(id);
            if (spresult == 1 || spresult == -1)
            {
                this.AddToastMessage("Success", "Record deleted successfully", ToastType.Success);
            }
            else
            {
                this.AddToastMessage("Error", "Something went wrong", ToastType.Error);
            }
            return Content("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

this is an image of output with both (Error and What I want in output)
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsT3Z.jpg)

Please, Can anyone give me a solution.?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: The 500 error is coming from the server side logic you call from `$.get("/Currency/GetRecordFromId?id=" + id, ...` I'd suggest checking the response text of the error to see the full stack trace and then stepping through the MVC logic to see where the exact issue is, as the JS itself is fine.

Comment: Response Text is blank in the browser...I trace many times but fail to catch an error..:(

Comment: In which case set a breakpoint and step through the C# code when you make a request

Comment: when Get request call I put a debugger and it will work...but after calling in the bracket I put debugger ...at that point response not come.that debugger not work